# androidx appbarlayout problem in migrated project

Tags: android-appbarlayout, androidx

I recently refactored my project to androidx. but now it has a fatal exception.when i run the project i face the error with coordinatorlayout and appbarLayout and incompatible with androidx. I guess I have to use an androidx alternative for AppBarLayout but I searched for it and can't find any alternative.

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not inflate Behavior subclass android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior
```

this is my xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:layout_scrollInterpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/allAdsMain_recyclerView_mainCategories"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".all_ad_main" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/allAdsMain_recyclerView_ads"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/allAdsMain_button_adRegister"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundshapebtn"
    android:text="@string/call_for_price"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're still referencing a support library dependency under your `NestedScrollView`.

Change:

`app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

to

`app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"`

You're already using it in your `CoordinatorLayout`. Next time you run into this type of issue, you can use code complete in Android Studio while trying to create (in this case) an `AppBarLayout` and check the package of the version Android Studio wants to import. If your dependencies are setup right, there should only be the androidx option,